# What is the range of dates for which pyephem is accurate?

Tags: pyephem

I'm currently using Swiss Ephemeris, but it requires external data files which are quite large. So, I was considering [Pyephem](http://rhodesmill.org/pyephem/), which seems to work well without any data files. But what is the range of dates over which it is valid/accurate? SwissEph works for nearly 10,000 years. I'm mostly interested in the couple of centuries bordering 3000 BCE and 1900 CE. The quantities of interest are sunrise and sunset times, as well as solar and lunar longitudes.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that PyEphem is thoroughly scientific-grade. It leverages LibAstro and XEphem, so I believe it is as accurate as they are, which is *very* accurate.

You are definitely golden for your centuries around 1900 CE. In his Halley Comet example, Brandon Rhodes uses the year 1066. See [fixed-objects-precession-and-epochs](http://rhodesmill.org/pyephem/tutorial.html#fixed-objects-precession-and-epochs).

I found your question because I was curious about epochs and years in ancient history too. If you look at my [github issue](https://github.com/brandon-rhodes/pyephem/issues/61) about a similar question, you'll see I got the same results as some pro-astronomers 100000 years ago and 100000 years in the future.

Hopefully this answers your question :)

Comment: Update: Brandon Rhodes answered my related question. He found that the precession formulas in PyEphem and SkyField limit changing the epoch to ±20000 years. What does this mean for you? Well, you are well-within these limits if changing year *or* epoch. If you are solely changing year, you are not under this constraint. His example notebook [github-issue-61.ipynb](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/brandon-rhodes/pyephem/blob/master/issues/github-issue-61.ipynb) clearly explains this.